# Why is not class from other project found when compile with Maven?

Tags: java, maven

Below I describe more about the issue I have.

**Description**
I making a program using Spring REST Interface (see code below) and I have problem to compile code with Maven (see problem section). I have no problem to compile the code using my IDE Eclipse.

**Problem**
When I compile my code with Maven in command line in Windows
I use *mvn clean compile* but then get the fault message:
*[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project stocks-rest: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/tobbe/eclipse/student-services/src/main/java/Rest/StocksRestApi.java:[25,18] package Exceptions does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/tobbe/eclipse/student-services/src/main/java/Rest/StocksRestApi.java:[83,184] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ElementSizeException
[ERROR]   location: class Rest.StocksRestApi*

I have the jar in local reposity (m2) and it contain ElementSizeException.

File structure where ElementSizeException is stored (other project):
*C:\tobbe\eclipse\ws_privat\Other\src\main\java\Exceptions (Enums)\ElementSizeException.java*

My code:

```
/**
 * Version 1.0.2
 */
package Rest;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import Enums.Market;
import Enums.REA_Stock_State;
import Enums.Stock_State;
**Fault**import Exceptions.ElementSizeException;
import REA.REAMain;
import REA.REAStock;
import Stocks.Logger;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class StocksRestApi 
{
    private Logger iLogger = null; 
    
    public StocksRestApi()
    {
        iLogger = new Logger();   
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(StocksRestApi.class, args);
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value="/rea")
    public String rea() throws HeadlessException, MalformedURLException, IOException, AWTException, InterruptedException, UnsupportedFlavorException, IllegalClassFormatException, **Fault**ElementSizeException 
    {
        List<REAStock> stocks = REAMain.doAnalyze(true, Market.LARGE_CAP_STHLM_KEYFIGURE, REA_Stock_State.REA_ANALYZE, Stock_State.UNKNOWN, iLogger); 
        String allStocks = ""; 
    
        for(int index = 0; index < stocks.size(); index++)
        {
             allStocks += index + 1 + ". " + stocks.get(index).getName() + " "; 
             if(index < 20)
             {
                 allStocks += "<br>"; 
             }
             if(index == 19)
             {
                 allStocks += "------------------------------<br>"; 
             }
         }
        return allStocks;
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>tobbe</groupId>
    <artifactId>stocks-rest</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tobbe</groupId>
        <artifactId>Stocks_Backend</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Question**
Why do I get compilation fault and why is not ElementSizeException (other own project which jar is in m2 and contain functionaly) found when using Maven?

Comment: Did you ran the `mvn install` goal on your backend project?

Comment: I ran mvn: 
mvn clean compile 
mvn project 
and last on the Other project: 
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\tobbe\eclipse\ws_privat\Other\target\Other-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=tobbe -DartifactId=Other -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar

Do I miss something?

Comment: Why not `mvn install` (without arguments) in the local m2 repository? This is where maven is looking for dependecies. When you trying to resolve the pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is unable to find the a dependency containing the imported class, and it is most likely because a dependency is missing or incorrectly referenced in the POM.

Verify that the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>tobbe</groupId>
    <artifactId>Stocks_Backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Is actually matching the [GAV](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html) for the artifact installed by the project creating the required dependency, and that it is containing "Exceptions.ElementSizeException".

Also consider using the few simple [Java naming conventions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html) when naming your packages, classes, methods, and other Java types.

Comment: Regarding dependency it is as following: Other (latest release 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)->Stocks_Backend (latest release 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, depedent on Other 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)->Stocks_Rest (latest release 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT, depedent on Stocks_Backend 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)

So dependency looks right what I can see!

Comment: And you have verified that the dependencies are present in your Maven repository with the GAV specified?

Comment: Ty all for trying to help! I found why compilation fails, but I don't know why it works with eclipse. The fault that was done is rather simple and actually a bit embarrising.  The fault was done in POM and I missed to include dependency for the project Other. Actually not easy  to (or imposible) find with the current problem description. I am glad the issue is now resolvded!

Comment: It works in Eclipse because the project is in your build path and you are not building with Maven in Eclipse (I guess).
It was pretty obvious that you missed a dependency, and also what I wrote in my answer. Finding the missing dependency was a task left for you to do. Hopefully you gained some experience with Maven from this.